# xcode do a random method

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, random, methods

Hi every one I'm french so scuse me for my english. Well what I want to do is that every second I do a random method between four methods. how can I do this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere you need to start the timer

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(randomMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Then implement the method that will be called:

```
-(void)randomMethod:(NSTimer *)timer {

    if (shouldStop) {
        [timer invalidate];
        return;
    } 

    int rand = arc4random() % 4;

    switch (rand) {
        case 0: 
            [self method0];
            break;
        case 1:
            [self method1];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self method2];
            break;
        case 3:
            [self method3];
            break;
    }
}
```

then later, at some point if you want to stop it, set `shouldStop` to true.

Comment: ok but my methods animate the ball and they are all in the same mainloop with a CadisplayLink of 60fps .

Comment: At some point you will need to learn to work it out yourself. I have provided you with timer code, random code, and the switch statement code. This is what your question asks. If you have other questions, put them up as a different question.

Comment: justa final question where and how can we make shouldStop to true.

Comment: anywhere you want. It should be set to true whenever you want to stop the timer, either from another button press, after an event is triggered, or by using another timer to call a method to stop it after a certain amount of time.

Comment: is it possible to stop it for amoment and restart it at another point

Answer (score 3):

You want a random integer number between 1 and 4 and then a case statement to execute the corresponding selectors, right?

Comment: int randomNumber = 1+ arc4random() %(4); to get the number [1,4]

Comment: an then how to execute the corresponding selectors ?

Comment: You'll need a NSTimer that executes every second a method with a "case randomNumber" statement with your four selectors as options.

Answer (score 1):

array of 4 strings (the names of your methods), generate random int between 0 and 3 then use NSSelectorFromString to call.

Answer (score 1):

For example you have four methods:

```
//put them on array as strings
NSArray *arrayOfSelectors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"eat", @"drink", @"run", @"sleep", nil];

//generate a random number based on the number of selectors inside the array
int randomNumber = arc4random()%arrayOfSelectors.count;

//call the method
//assumes that someObject really implement the methods inside the array, else your app will crash
[someObject performSelector:NSSelectorFromString([arrayOfSelectors objectAtIndex:randomNumber])];
```

1. -(void)eat;
2. -(void)drink;
3. -(void)run;
4. -(void)sleep;

Comment: and then.... there is not the if(randomNumber=1) or somthing like this , to call the method attached to the number

Comment: His answer is OK Arvin, it does call one of the methods at random. Copy that to XCode and Cmd+click on the methods to see its documentation.

Comment: but how can we use these number to call the method .that is where my problem is .

Answer (score 0):

First create the timer:

```
NSTimer *t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0
                                              target: self
                                            selector:@selector(selectorSwitcher:)
                                            userInfo: nil repeats:YES];
NSRunLoop *runner = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runner addTimer:t forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Then implement the switcher:

```
-(void)selectorSwitcher:(NSTimer *)timer {

    int randomNumber = 1+ arc4random() %(4);
    switch (randomNumber) {
        case 1:
            [self selector1];
            break;
        case 2:
            [self selector2];
            break;
        case 3:
            [self selector3];
            break;
        case 4:
            [self selector4];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```